# using LLVM-IR ptr with struct

Tags: pointers, llvm, llvm-ir

```
struct foo{
    int val;
};

int get(foo *s){
    return s->val;
}
```

ir generation for the code sample mentioned above:

```
%foo = type { i32 }


define i32 @func_get(ptr %s) {
entry:
  %s1 = alloca ptr, align 8
  store ptr %s, ptr %s1, align 8
  %0 = getelementptr inbounds { i32 }, ptr %s1, i32 0, i32 0
  %1 = load i32, ptr %0, align 4
  ret i32 %1
}
```

It is not producing the desired results. I'm having trouble getting the address of the struct element in @func_get.
How can I obtain the struct element using the struct pointer?